# Is it better to use Action Script 2 or 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I just started learning how to code games in flash using a tutorial that was for action script 2. I am wondering if you can accomplish enough in action script 2 or if I should just learn how to use 3. I heard you can do a lot more with action script 3 but is it really that important for me to switch? (I am not going to make any 3D games).

Answer (score 7):

ActionScript 2 is a rough language with a very hacked on OO system and poor typing.

The ONLY reason to still use it is if you are maintaining an old flash app. Don't use it today. AS3 is MUCH better.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to learn AS3, its fully object orientated, and a natural step forward from AS2. We have recently inherited a bunch of flash projects that are one huge mess of AS1 and AS2 and are having problems finding people who would take on the task of rewriting everything in AS3.

If you are looking for maintainability, use of the best tech you possibly can, and want to learn to write good OO code, definitely go down the AS3 path.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to use AS3 is because it makes displaying and interacting with things onscreen easier to code.

Some major improvements in AS3:

1. Let's say you have a MovieClip `mcOuter` that contains another MovieClip, `mcInner`. AS3 makes it easy for `mcOuter` to receive a mouseover event when you mouse over `mcInner`.
2. AS3 uses closures, which means that event handling functions (e.g. for mouse over) work right without resorting to Delegate.

Generally, the functions and classes are much better organized in AS3 than in AS2.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only worked in AS2 You may find the syntax of AS3 a little more complex at first - I certainly did at the time - but once you've progressed a little further and want to expand your horizons, you'll make your life a million times easier by making the jump.

Speaking as someone who has to maintain couple of apps I wrote years ago in AS2 I constantly wish I had the time to port them to AS3.  Why?

1. The event model. If this were the only improvement it'd still make AS3 a billion times better than AS2.
2. Richer API across the board.  Particularly useful if you make games, as you have lower-level access to pretty much every facet of your assets, esp. sound and bitmaps.

   Native support for XML/E4X, 3D geometry, RTL languages, etc., etc., etc.

   The display list metaphor: much simpler and more robust IMO

   Access to the hundreds of amazing classes out there - BulkLoader being just one - that don't have an AS2 version

   Performance

   Performance

   Performance
   and...

   Performance

OK, so I'm labouring the point about faster execution, but seriously, AS3 is a quantum leap ahead. The TweenLite website has an interesting speed comparison if you're interested:
http://blog.greensock.com/tweening-speed-test/